# How to use SQL query with CosmosDB client in C# .NET Core 2.1 API app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to use an Azure CosmosDB (former DocumentDB) repository in an API I am creating (I'm quite new to C#). I have managed to get a result with all documents using the client.CreateDocumentQuery method without passing a SQL query to it. However, when I pass a SQL query, program execution hangs and the controller responds with 404. I've tried to add a try-catch around it but I get no exception or anything.

Using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core Version 1.9.1.

I've tried many things, other methods and also LINQ, but got nothing to work. If you have a look at this sample method, could you give me an example on how to correctly query and get a result from the document collection? I would really appreciate it!UPDATE: I updated the SQL a bit. Have tried with hard coded parameter and have tested it in the data explorer where it works. Execution seems to freeze on `*var feedResponse = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>();*`

```
        // Document repository
    public async Task<IEnumerable<JObject>> GetDocsFromCollectionAsync(string someId)
        {
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey); 
        IDocumentQuery<JObject> documentQuery;
        var documentCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
        var queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };

            if (someId.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {   
                // This works
                documentQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(documentCollectionUri,queryOptions)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();
            } 
            else 
            {
                var query = new SqlQuerySpec(
                    "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.someId = @someId",
                    new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter { Name = "@someId", Value = someId } }));

                // This hangs during execution / returns 404 in the API controller
                documentQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(documentCollectionUri, query, queryOptions)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();
            }

        List<JObject> documents = new List<JObject>();

            while (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
            var feedResponse = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>();
            documents.AddRange(feedResponse);
            }

            return documents; // Return documents to API controller
        }
```

Comment: have you tried the query in azure's cosmos db data explorer?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the SQL to reflect what I've tried a bit more. Perhaps the issue with the async feedResponse, I am not sure what is going on there really, this is where it gets stuck at the moment.

Comment: Can you debug over this line `documentQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(documentCollectionUri, query, queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();` and make sure that the parameter is replaces properly? Just check what the `documentQuery.ToString()` value is. It should be the final query that will hit the database.

Comment: It looks like this: > documentQuery.ToString()
"{\"query\":\"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.someId = 'SomeId123'\",\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"@someId\",\"value\":\"SomeId123\"}]}"
> 
If I copy paste the query into the Azure Data Explorer it gives me the correct document as expected.

Comment: It might worth giving [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) a go. It's an ORM i wrote on top of the SDK and it has a more elegant way to query with sql so your whole code you be something like this: `await cosmosStore.QueryMultipleAsync<JObject>("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.someId = @someId", new { someId = someId})`.

Comment: @NickChapsas Does Cosmonaut work with serverless?  I get an exception when instantiating a CosmosStore<SomeModel>(storeSettings). ---
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Reading or replacing offers is not supported for serverless accounts.